# Что за оператор ^=

Tags: c#

Привествую, недавно увидел такой оператор ^=, но так и не нашел что он делает, применялся он к int, знаю что ^ это ислючения, но ^= да еще и для int. ЧТо это?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

^ - Исключающее ИЛИ (XOR)

```
int^=0xFF будет равносильно записи int=int^0xFF
```

Каждый бит числа будет сверен с таковым же битом второго числа и если биты не равны мы получим 1 на месте сравниваемого бита, иначе 0.

Таблица:

```
a  b  a^b
0  0   0
0  1   1
1  0   1
1  1   0
```

Пример:

```
 0100 0110
^0010 0010
=0110 0100
```

Comment: Имхо лучше привести таблицу истинности для xor'а, и наглядно и понятно :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Пожалуй согласен, добавил еще и таблицу =)