# Mysql SET в миграциях Yii2?

Tags: yii2

Подскажите, пожалуйста, при добавлении нового поля в таблицу с помощью миграции хочу сделать тип **SET**(0,1,2,3).
Как это указать в **yii2**?
`$this->addColumn('table', 'weekdays', $this->);`

Answer (score 0):

`$this->addColumn('table', 'weekdays ', "SET(0,1,2,3,4,5,6) NOT NULL");`

Comment: Т.е. до того как задать этот "очень сложный" вопрос вы не удосужились даже в поисковик заглянуть или в справку по Yii2? **задан 10 минут назад** -> **ответ дан 3 минуты назад**

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Нет.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков друг, а ты не пробовал открыть документацию или поисковик чтобы найти ответ на свой "очень сложный вопрос" по поводу оператора?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/920140/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80/920150#920150

Comment: Это был не мой **вопрос** для начала, а мой **ответ** =)))) разницы не видно? посмотрите оба мои вопроса и попробуйте прогуглить ответы на них вне этого форума =) и я вам больше скажу, попробуйте что в гугле что в яндексе ввести `^=` - если он вообще согласится искать - по теме ровно ноль ответов =)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, был не прав, прошу извинить.

Comment: Прошу прощенья если задел, просто за сегодня это второй примитивный вопрос по Yii2 котрый гуглится за минуту и описан(очень хорошо) в документации.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, нет, Вы полностью правы, впредь буду более воспитан и посмотрю документацию.